# Error when running R 3.0.1 from SAS/IML 9.3

Tags: r, version, sas

I'm trying to run R 3.0.1 from SAS 9.3 in SAS/IML and I get 2 errors:-
1- ERROR: SAS could not initialize the R language interface.

2- ERROR: The installed version of R cannot be used.  The entry point "R_Toplevel" could not be
       located.
Any idea if it's because the R version, and if so, what version of R should I use?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to http://blogs.sas.com/content/iml/2013/09/16/what-versions-of-r-are-supported-by-sas/

With SAS 9.3  you can only use R 2.9.1 -- 2.15.3

If you upgrade to SAS 9.4, you can use up to R 3.0.1

If you upgrade to SAS 9.4m1 (when it is released) then you can use R 3.0.2

Comment: Thanks a lot, appreciate it.

Comment: Any advice or suggestions on dealing with multiple R installations? i.e. can SAS be told to use R 2.15.1 if I also have R 3.0.2 installed?