# SAS to R configuration through IML

Tags: r, sas, sas-iml

Looking to submit statements from SAS to R through the [submit/R] [endsubmit] statements.  I am running version 9.3 and have modified the sasV9.cfg file to include the -RLANG statement. However, when I run the following code

```
proc options option=rlang;
run;
```

in SAS to test that the RLANG option is turned on, I get the following error message:
"  SAS (r) Proprietary Software Release 9.3  TS1M2
 NORLANG           Do not support access to R language interfaces"

Thanks in advance for your assistance.

Comment: Are you sure you updated the correct sasv9.cfg file?

Comment: ran a file search for sasv9 and it only returned one file - the file I modified.

Comment: Your shortcut to SAS.exe likely has a mention of the cfg file.  Depending on your environment you might have a file in a network location to allow administrators to have a consistent config for all users, or any number of other issues. It's also likely you require admin rights to modify the config file - if not it may not have saved (verify that the change is reflected)

Comment: I have verified that the change is reflected in the config file

Comment: Does it work if you start the exe with -RLANG?  ie `"c:\pathtosas\sas.exe" -RLANG`

Comment: Joe, do you mean modify the config file to so that the path to the sas.exe is before the -RLANG statement?  If so, then yes I did try this but unfortunatley it didn't work.

Comment: No, I mean in the shortcut that you use to run SAS (or if you run in the command line, in the command line portion).  You can either set RLANG in the config or in the command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An alternative way to set the RLANG option is in the shortcut.  Add -RLANG to the shortcut's Target (it may already have other options in it, like -CONFIG "...sasv9.cfg" etc.).

```
"c:\pathtosas.exe\sas.exe" -RLANG
```

Comment: Just to summarize for future people: 1. type "run" in dialogue box, push enter.  paste the path to the exe file as above with the option: "c:\pathtosas.exe\sas.exe" -RLANG ... this worked for me after I downloaded an old version of R.  The match-up of R to SAS is given at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19262401/error-when-running-r-3-0-1-from-sas-iml-9-3